# Java curve fitting library

Tags: java, curve-fitting

I'm hoping to find a simple library that can take a series of 2 dimensional points and give me back a larger series of points that model the curve. Basically, I want to get the effect of curve fitting like this sample from JFreeChart:

[image]

The problem with JFreeChart is that the code does not provide this type of api. I even looked at the source and the algorithm is tightly coupled to the actual drawing.

Comment: Question being "on hold": One might reword the question to give example code in Java of Curve Fitting code (of course that code WILL pull in some libraries, so one can see that as a recommendation). This question is not about JFreeChart, which just TAKES the points and DISPLAYS them but does not GENERATE additional points. I am actually amazed that Linked and Related do not show exactly that question.

Answer (score 10):

[Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) has a nice series of algorithms, in particular "SplineInterpolator", see the [API docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html)

An example in which we call the interpolation functions for alpha(x), beta(x) from Groovy:

```
package example.com

import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.SplineInterpolator
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialSplineFunction

import statec.Extrapolate.Value;

class Interpolate {

    enum Value {
        ALPHA, BETA
    }

    def static xValues     = [
        -284086,
        -94784,
        31446,
        354837,
        667782,
        982191
    ]
    def static alphaValues = [
        71641,
        78245,
        80871,
        94045,
        105780,
        119616
    ]
    def static betaValues = [
        95552,
        103413,
        108667,
        128456,
        144686,
        171953
    ]

    static def getValueByName(Value value, int i) {
        def res
        switch (value) {
            case Value.ALPHA:
                res = alphaValues[i]
                break
            case Value.BETA:
                res = betaValues[i]
                break
            default:
                assert false
        }
        return res
    }

    static PolynomialSplineFunction interpolate(Value value) {
        def yValues = []
        int i = 0
        xValues.each {
            def y = getValueByName(value, i++)
            yValues << (y as Double)
        }
        SplineInterpolator spi = new SplineInterpolator()
        return spi.interpolate(xValues as double[], yValues as double[])
    }

    static void main(def argv) {
        //
        // Create a map mapping a Value instance to its interpolating function
        //
        def interpolations = [:]
        Value.values().each {
            interpolations[it] = interpolate(it)
        }
        //
        // Create an array of new x values to compute display.
        // Make sure the last "original" value is in there!
        // Note that the newxValues MUST stay within the range of the original xValues!
        //
        def newxValues = []
        for (long x = xValues[0] ; x < xValues[-1] ; x+=25000) {
            newxValues << x
        }
        newxValues << xValues[-1]
        //
        // Write interpolated values for ALPHA and BETA, adding the original values in columns 4 and 5
        //
        System.out << "X , ALPHA, BETA, X_orig, ALPHA_orig, BETA_orig" << "\n"
        int origIndex = 0
        newxValues.each { long x ->
            def alpha_ipol = interpolations[Value.ALPHA].value(x)
            def beta_ipol  = interpolations[Value.BETA].value(x)
            String out = "${x} ,  ${alpha_ipol} , ${beta_ipol}"
            if (x >= xValues[origIndex]) {
                out += ", ${xValues[origIndex]}, ${alphaValues[origIndex]}, ${betaValues[origIndex]}"
                origIndex++
            }
            System.out << out << "\n"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The resulting output, plotted in LibreOffice Calc]

And now for an off-topic example for EXTRAPOLATIONS, because it's fun. Here we use the same data as above, but extrapolate using an 2nd-degree polynomial. And the appropriate classes, of course. Again, in Groovy:

```
package example.com

import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialFunction
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.PolynomialFitter
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.WeightedObservedPoint
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.SimpleVectorValueChecker
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.vector.jacobian.GaussNewtonOptimizer

class Extrapolate {

    enum Value {
        ALPHA, BETA
    }

    def static xValues     = [
        -284086,
        -94784,
        31446,
        354837,
        667782,
        982191
    ]
    def static alphaValues = [
        71641,
        78245,
        80871,
        94045,
        105780,
        119616
    ]
    def static betaValues = [
        95552,
        103413,
        108667,
        128456,
        144686,
        171953
    ]

    static def getValueByName(Value value, int i) {
        def res
        switch (value) {
            case Value.ALPHA:
                res = alphaValues[i]
                break
            case Value.BETA:
                res = betaValues[i]
                break
            default:
                assert false
        }
        return res
    }

    static PolynomialFunction extrapolate(Value value) {
        //
        // how to check that we converged
        //
        def checker
        A: {
            double relativeThreshold = 0.01
            double absoluteThreshold = 10
            int maxIter = 1000
            checker = new SimpleVectorValueChecker(relativeThreshold, absoluteThreshold, maxIter)
        }
        //
        // how to fit
        //
        def fitter
        B: {
            def useLUdecomposition = true
            def optimizer = new GaussNewtonOptimizer(useLUdecomposition, checker)
            fitter = new PolynomialFitter(optimizer)
            int i = 0
            xValues.each {
                def weight = 1.0
                def y = getValueByName(value, i++)
                fitter.addObservedPoint(new WeightedObservedPoint(weight, it, y))
            }
        }
        //
        // fit using a 2-degree polynomial; guess at a linear function at first
        // "a0 + (a1 * x) + (a2 * x²)"; a linear guess mean a2 == 0
        //
        def params
        C: {
            def mStart = getValueByName(value,0)
            def mEnd   = getValueByName(value,-1)
            def xStart = xValues[0]
            def xEnd   = xValues[-1]
            def a2 = 0
            def a1 = (mEnd - mStart) / (xEnd - xStart) // slope
            def a0 = mStart - (xStart * a1) // 0-intersection
            def guess = [a0 , a1 , a2]
            params = fitter.fit(guess as double[])
        }
        //
        // make polynomial
        //
        return new PolynomialFunction(params)
    }

    static void main(def argv) {
        //
        // Create a map mapping a Value instance to its interpolating function
        //
        def extrapolations = [:]
        Value.values().each {
            extrapolations[it] = extrapolate(it)
        }
        //
        // New x, this times reaching out past the range of the original xValues
        //
        def newxValues = []
        for (long x = xValues[0] - 400000L ; x < xValues[-1] + 400000L ; x += 10000) {
            newxValues << x
        }
        //
        // Write the extrapolated series ALPHA and BETA, adding the original values in columns 4 and 5
        //
        System.out << "X , ALPHA, BETA, X_orig, ALPHA_orig, BETA_orig" << "\n"
        int origIndex = 0
        newxValues.each { long x ->
            def alpha_xpol = extrapolations[Value.ALPHA].value(x)
            def beta_xpol  = extrapolations[Value.BETA].value(x)
            String out = "${x} ,  ${alpha_xpol} , ${beta_xpol}"
            if (origIndex < xValues.size() && x >= xValues[origIndex]) {
                out += ", ${xValues[origIndex]}, ${alphaValues[origIndex]}, ${betaValues[origIndex]}"
                origIndex++
            }
            System.out << out << "\n"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The resulting output, plotted in LibreOffice Calc]

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but a quick Google search revealed that Bezier curves are implemented in http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.Double.html

Then, you can getPathIterator() from this curve and with that, according to what documentation says, you get the "coordinates of shape boundaries", which, i suppose, is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, he does not want to do this. He needs to compute control points of the curve using spline interpolation or some heuristics method.

Comment: I suggest you better read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Bezier curves is one of the ways to model these curves. By having the coordinates of points on this curve, he effectively gets what he wants.