# Approximate a R2 line by a set of points

Tags: java, c++, line, point, approximate

I'm working on an application with statistic analysis, and I need some help.
Given a set of n points, how can I approximate a line by them. I'm sure there is an algorithm but I couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic is called linear regression, or [ordinary least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares). You should be able to find more details in any linear algebra or stat book.

A Java implementation can be found [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/97data/LinearRegression.java.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to fit a straight line, I suggest you look at [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). [This old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878200/java-curve-fitting-library) handles the more general case of curve fitting in Java and eventually recommends [CurveFitting Java](http://curvefitting.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: For fitting curves there's non-linear regression. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting